# Amcharts balloon box shows the time value as "24:05" instead of "00:05"

Tags: javascript, html, charts, amcharts

I am using Amcharts for generating chart. The chart is getting rendered well but on mouse hover, the balloon box displays the time value as "24:05" instead of "00:05"

I have data in this format :

```
var chartData = [{
        "batchName":"abc",
        "expectedEndTime": "00:05",
        "actualEndTime": "00:05",
    },
     {
       "batchName":"cde",
        "expectedEndTime": "01:01",
        "actualEndTime": "02:02"
    },
    {
        "batchName":"def",
        "expectedEndTime": "00:48",
        "actualEndTime": "02:09"
    },
    ---------------
    ---------------
```

And the configuration I have done as :

```
"graphs": [{
               "lineAlpha": 0.9,
               "type": "line",
               "lineThickness": 1.5,
               "bullet": "round",
               "lineColor": "#0D338C",
               "bulletBorderColor": "#0D338C",
               "bulletBorderThickness": 0.2,
               "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.5,
               "valueField": "expectedEndTime",
               "title": "Expected End Time",            
               "dateFormat": "HH:NN",
               "labelPosition": "top",
               "labelColor": "red",
               "valueAxis": "v1",
               "labelText": "[[labelExpected]]",
               "balloonText": "Estimated End Time : <b>[[value]]</b>"
            },
           ---------------------------
           ---------------------------
```

Here is my  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1r7fq2d/10/)

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AmCharts date format documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-date-time/) seems to be backward.  Try `KK:NN` for a date format.

This is their table.  But `H` and `K` seem to be swapped in the version you use:

```
┌──────┬───┬──────┬────┬──────────────┐
│ hour │ h │ 1..2 │ 11 │ Hour [1-12]. │
│      │ H │ 1..2 │ 13 │ Hour [0-23]. │
│      │ K │ 1..2 │  0 │ Hour [0-11]. │
│      │ k │ 1..2 │ 24 │ Hour [1-24]. │
└──────┴───┴──────┴────┴──────────────┘
```

```js
var chartData = [{"actualEndTime": "00:05", "batchName": "abc", "expectedEndTime": "00:05"}, {"actualEndTime": "02:02", "batchName": "cde", "expectedEndTime": "01:01"}, {"actualEndTime": "02:09", "batchName": "def", "expectedEndTime": "00:48"}, {"actualEndTime": "02:36", "batchName": "efg", "expectedEndTime": "00:54"}, {"actualEndTime": "02:46", "batchName": "fgh", "expectedEndTime": "01:35"}, {"actualEndTime": "04:36", "batchName": "ghi", "expectedEndTime": "03:15", "labelActual": "04:36", "labelExpected": "03:15"}, {"actualEndTime": "04:49", "batchName": "hij", "expectedEndTime": "05:00"}, {"actualEndTime": "05:09", "batchName": "ijk", "expectedEndTime": "05:18"}, {"actualEndTime": "06:10", "batchName": "jkl", "expectedEndTime": "05:30"}, {"actualEndTime": "04:32", "batchName": "klm", "expectedEndTime": "06:18", "labelActual": "04:32", "labelExpected": "06:18"}, {"actualEndTime": "06:00", "batchName": "lmn", "expectedEndTime": "06:00"}, {"actualEndTime": "06:17", "batchName": "mno", "expectedEndTime": "06:31"}, {"actualEndTime": "05:38", "batchName": "nop", "expectedEndTime": "05:41"}, {"actualEndTime": "05:32", "batchName": "opq", "expectedEndTime": "07:38"}, {"actualEndTime": "08:23", "batchName": "pqr", "expectedEndTime": "07:18", "labelActual": "08:23", "labelExpected": "07:18"}, {"actualEndTime": "07:32", "batchName": "qrs", "expectedEndTime": "08:00", "labelActual": "07:32", "labelExpected": "08:00"}, {"actualEndTime": "07:57", "batchName": "rst", "expectedEndTime": "07:04"}, {"actualEndTime": "08:58", "batchName": "stu", "expectedEndTime": "10:30"}, {"actualEndTime": "09:48", "batchName": "tuv", "expectedEndTime": "11:30"}, {"actualEndTime": "14:10", "batchName": "uvw", "expectedEndTime": "11:30", "labelActual": "14:10", "labelExpected": "11:30"}, {"actualEndTime": "14:52", "batchName": "vwx", "expectedEndTime": "11:30", "labelActual": "14:52", "labelExpected": "11:30"}];

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "backgroundColor": 'blue',
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "zoomOutText": '',
    "color": "black",
    "dataDateFormat": "HH:NN",
    "legend": {
        "useGraphSettings": true
    },
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "position": "left",
        "axisColor": "#472F52",
        "title": "Time of the Day",
        "type": "date",
        "axisThickness": 2,
        "markPeriodChange": false,
        "autoGridCount": false,
        "minimumDate": "00:00",
        "maximumDate": "23:00",
        "gridCount": 20,
        "minPeriod": "ss",
    }

    ],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "lineAlpha": 0.9,
        "type": "line",
        "lineThickness": 1.5,
        "bullet": "round",
        "lineColor": "#0D338C",
        "bulletBorderColor": "#0D338C",
        "bulletBorderThickness": 0.2,
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.5,
        "valueField": "expectedEndTime",
        "title": "Expected End Time",
        "dateFormat": "KK:NN",
        "labelPosition": "top",
        "labelColor": "red",
        "valueAxis": "v1",
        "labelText": "[[labelExpected]]",
        "balloonText": "Estimated End Time : <b>[[value]]</b>"
    },
    {
        "lineAlpha": 0.9,
        "type": "line",
        "lineThickness": 1.5,
        "lineColor": "#C63F05",
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderColor": "#C63F05",
        "bulletBorderThickness": 0.2,
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.5,
        "valueField": "actualEndTime",
        "title": "Actual End Time",
        "dateFormat": "KK:NN",
        "labelPosition": "bottom",
        "labelColor": "blue",
        "valueAxis": "v1",
        "labelText": "[[labelActual]]",
        "balloonText": "Actual End Time : <b>[[value]]</b>"
    }
    ],
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "DD",
        "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
        "cursorColor": "#000000",
        "fullWidth": true,
        "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
        "zoomable": false
    },
    "categoryField": "batchName",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisThickness": 2,
        "axisColor": "#472F52",
        "autoGridCount": false,
        "gridCount": 1000,
        "title": "Batches",
        "labelRotation": 30
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "borderRadius": "10px",
        "text-align": "center",
        "pdfMake": {
            "content": ["'<Name of the Metric to be displayed dynamically>'",
                "                     ", "from <startDate> To <endDate>", {
                    "image": "reference", //exported image
                    "fit": [523.28, 769.89]
                }
            ]
        },
        "legend": {
            "position": "bottom", // or "right", "bottom" and "left" are possible
            "width": 200, // optional
            "height": 200 // optional
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 275px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sauyet! It worked for me. Now, I am just wondering if I can avoid the collision for data value labels (for the case of 'klm'- 6:18 & 4:32). If we can set the locations of these labels dynimacally. Any suggestion from you, would be a great support.

Comment: ++ vote up and I appreciate your quick response, thanks. Your valuable suggestions on above stuff would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid I have not idea.  I actually don't know AmCharts at all.  I simply looked at their documentation, saw that you seemed to have done it right, and played with the other values to discover what actually worked.  (You might want to raise an issue with them, in fact; either their code or their documentation is wrong.)  But I wouldn't know where to start with this one.

Comment: FYI, the correct date formatting documentation for the version he's using is located [here](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/). Your link is for v4 which isn't officially released at this time. `K` is not supported in `dataDateFormat`. He needs to use `JJ:NN`

Comment: Thanks.  It's good to know.  That was one of the first links to come up in the search engine.